Is there any way to upgrade Graphic card on laptops
Is there any way to upgrade the graphic card on laptops?

Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].

There are a variety of questions on this site about this already. Please review these: https://superuser.com/search?q=upgrade+laptop+video+card

In almost all cases, this is not possible in the sense of replacing the internal graphics card.
There are a few laptops that are created solely with the idea of being able to swap out different components, but if your laptop was capable of this, you would have bought it for this specific reason and you would not have needed to ask the question to begin with.
I know DELL made one laptop with this idea in mind, although I don't know if they allowed the GPU to be replaced or not, and the brand Framework specifically created their laptops with the idea that they are completely modular. I'm not aware of any other brand that would allow the replacement of a GPU.
That said, It is possible to ADD an external GPU using thunderbold and some USB-C ports. This is not a cheap solution, nor is it a portable one. Replacing the entire laptop is almost always the best solution.

It should be noted that Framework is doing an amazing job but the price is also very high.
